# Why stack is implemented as a linked list ? What is the need, why array implementation is not sufficient?

Tags: c, stack, linked-list

Many times, stack is implemented as a linked list, Is array representation not good enough, in array we can perform push pop easily, and linked list over array complicates the code, and has no advantage over array implementation.

Can you give any example where a linked list implementation is more beneficial, or we cant do without it.

Comment: The trouble with an array is that you have to pick a size.  A linked list is an easy workaround for that, albeit not very efficient.

Comment: Mostly it comes down to overuse of linked lists in general. Between poor cache utilization and per-node pointer overhead, good uses for them are relatively rare (and most of the standard arguments about doing lots of random insertions and deletions don't hold up in testing or actual use).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Cache behaviour and pointer overhead can be minimized by unrolling the linked list, controlling the allocation (putting nodes together), and a few other tricks. But yeah, it's not the go-to all rounder data structure some people claim it is, and in particular it isn't simple at all with those optimizations.

Comment: @user183177 - Can you give an example of a situation in which a stack is implemented as a linked list?  You say "many times", but I've never seen one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that many practical implementations of stacks *are* written using arrays. For example, the .NET Stack implementation uses an array as a backing store.

Arrays are typically more efficient because you can keep the stack nodes all nearby in contiguous memory that can fit nicely in your fast cache lines on the processor.

I imagine you see textbook implementations of stacks that use linked lists because they're easier to write and don't force you to write a little bit of extra code to manage the backing array store as well as come up with a growth/copy/reserve space heuristic.

In addition, if you're really pressed to use little memory, a linked list implementation might make sense since you don't "waste" space that's not currently used. However, on modern processors with plenty of memory, it's typically better to use arrays to gain the cache advantages they offer rather than worry about page faults with the linked list approach.

Comment: Unless the items being stored are relatively large, a linked list tends to waste a lot of space. For example, a doubly-linked list of `int`s will typically use at least twice, and often four times as much space for the pointers as the data you intended to store. An array-based representation will nearly always do at least as well in this respect.

Comment: @JerryCoffin A doubly-linked list using two pointers per node is obvious, but how would it use four words? Are you talking about allocator metadata when the nodes are allocated separately?

Comment: @delnan: no, I was thinking of (for one example) Microsoft's 64-bit compiler, where an `int` is 32 bits, and a pointer 64 bits, so each node would store 4 bytes of data and 16 bytes of pointers. Being fair, however, there's no reason to use a doubly linked list for a stack.

Answer (score 1):

Size of array is limited and predefined. When you dont know how many of them are there then linked list is a perfect option.

More Elaborated comparison:-(+ for dominating linked list and - for array)

`Size and type constraint:-`

1. (+) Further members of array are aligned at equal distance and need contiguous memory while on the other side link list can provide non contiguous memory solution, so sometimes it is good for memory as well in case of huge data(avoids cpu polling for resource).
2. (+) Suppose in a case you are using an array as stack, and the array is of type int.Now how will you accommodate a double in it??

`Portability`

1. (+) Array can cause exceptions like index out of bound exceptions but you can increase the chain anytime in a linked list.

`Speed and performance`

1. (-)If its about performance, then obviously most of the complexity fall around O(1) for arrays.In case of a linked list you will have to select a starting node to start the tracing and this adds to performance penalty.

Comment: Have you heard about dynamic over-allocating arrays?

Comment: @delnan: This increases the complexity of `push`es. Not something I'd expect from a stack.

Comment: That only bumps it from worst-case O(1) to amortized O(1) and that's plenty good for almost all use cases. The amortized bit only matters if you do realtime, but as I argued in my own answer, then you likely wouldn't use a linked list either. At least not a run of the mill implementation.

Comment: RE size and type constraint: In portable C, you cannot simply throw a list node with a different item type either. The union approach you mention reserves as much space as the *largest* member requires, and is equally applicable to arrays.

Comment: @delnan:- can you please make necessary edits, I have no issue in making it a community wiki answer.Question is really good.

Answer (score 0):

When the size of the stack can vary greatly you waste space if you have generalized routines which always allocate a huge array.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a fixed size array has limitation of knowing maximum size before hand.
If you consider `dynamic array` then [Linked List vs. Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_lists_vs._dynamic_arrays) covers the details including complexities for performing operations.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is implemented using Linked List because Push and Pop operations are of O(1) time complexities, compared to O(n) for arrays. (apart from flexible size advantage in Linked List)

Comment: how can push and pop in arrays have O(n) complexity ? I think you are wrong, The correct answer is Size of array is limited and predefined. When you dont know how many of them are there then linked list is a perfect option.

Comment: Thanks for correction!! I had dynamic array in mind and thought that copying of element will take time, but there also amortized time complexity will be o(1).